# Does Shell command from Login script affect scripts synchronously setting

Tags: windows, login-script

I have had to alter one of our login script to check to see if windows is 64 or 32 bit, then shell out to another command based on this.

Does shelling out from the login script affect the run scripts synchronously policy option, i still dont want the user to get to their desktop until the commands have finished running

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your login script is a cmd script  and that also what you're using to shell then things should run synchronously, as long as nothing in the script is manually spawning a background process. That should be the case for most scripting tools, actually. The login script will wait until the shelled commands return. Do note, though, that you'll have to handle any errors that might get raised by the shelled out commands before your users get their desktops.